# Alternative update SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for an alternative for this query. I know that such query will end up with invalid identifier in Oracle. So please give me the same query for updating one filed from another field in another table.

```
update RBT_CMP_RECOM_9304 
set FIRST_RECOM_NAME=(select rbt_cmp_base_code.RBT_NAME 
                        from rbt_cmp_base_code 
                       where rbt_cmp_base_code.RBT_CODE=RBT_CMP_RECOM_9304.FIRST_RECOM)
where rbt_cmp_base_code.RBT_CODE=RBT_CMP_RECOM_9304.FIRST_RECOM;
```

FYI:

`RBT_CMP_RECOM_9304=(firt_recom,first_recom_name)`

```
RBT_CMP_BASE_CODE = (rbt_code, rbt_name)
```

I get this error when I try it:

> ORA-00904: RBT_CMP_BASE_CODE.RBT_CODE: invalid identifier

Regards.

Comment: Why are you looking for an alternative when this works?

Comment: This does not work, it returns invalid identifier.

Comment: I do not know the schema. This is debugging and what is the error message

Comment: ORA-00904: RBT_CMP_BASE_CODE.RBT_CODE: invalid identifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to repeat the subquery:

```
update RBT_CMP_RECOM_9304 r
    set FIRST_RECOM_NAME = (select bc.RBT_NAME 
                            from rbt_cmp_base_code bc
                            where bc.RBT_CODE = r.FIRST_RECOM
                           )
    where exists (select 1
                  from rbt_cmp_base_code bc
                  where bc.RBT_CODE = r.FIRST_RECOM
                 );
```

EDIT:

If you are getting an error that more than one row is returned, then you have to decide which value.  Nothing in your code suggests that this might be an issue (hint:  sample data and desired results always help a question).

The easiest solution is to use and aggregation function:

```
update RBT_CMP_RECOM_9304 r
    set FIRST_RECOM_NAME = (select max(bc.RBT_NAME)
                            from rbt_cmp_base_code bc
                            where bc.RBT_CODE = r.FIRST_RECOM
                           )
    where exists (select 1
                  from rbt_cmp_base_code bc
                  where bc.RBT_CODE = r.FIRST_RECOM
                 );
```

But you might want to fix the `rbt_cmp_base_code` table so it doesn't have duplicates.  From the table name, it sounds like there should be one row per code.

Comment: You new query returns: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more that one row.